# How to use material-ui TextField with react-phone-number-input

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, material-ui

I'd like to supply a material UI TextField component to the PhoneInput component from react-phone-number-input as the `inputComponent` prop.

However, I don't seem to be able to successfully apply the ref. Although I see the Material UI TextField component rendered to the UI and state is successfully updated with the value, it keeps loosing focus after the first value has been typed.

```
import React, { forwardRef, createRef } from 'react';
import { TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
import 'react-phone-number-input/style.css';
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-number-input';

const SampleComponent = ({ handleChange }) => {

const phoneInput = forwardRef((props, ref) => {

return (
  <TextField
    inputRef={ref}
    fullWidth
    label="Phone Number"
    variant="outlined"
    name="phone"
    onChange={handleChange}
  />
  );
});

const ref = createRef();
return (
    <PhoneInput ref={ref} inputComponent={phoneInput} />
   );
  };
```

Comment: Hi! Were you ever able to figure this out? I'm attempting the same thing at the moment. Thanks!

Comment: As a heads-up, I have a package for exactly this. https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-phone-number

Answer (score 25, accepted):

So I was able to get it to work using the following method. Any suggestions on how to improve this are more than welcome.

I have a separate file called `PhoneNumber.jsx`

```
import { forwardRef } from 'react'
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField'
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles'

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  input: {
    backgroundColor: '#fff'
  }
}))

const phoneInput = (props, ref) => {
  const classes = useStyles()

  return (

    <TextField
      {...props}
      InputProps={{
        className: classes.input
      }}
      inputRef={ref}
      fullWidth
      size='small'
      label='Phone Number'
      variant='outlined'
      name='phone'
    />
  )
}
export default forwardRef(phoneInput)
```

And my form file:

```
import PhoneInput from 'react-phone-number-input'
import CustomPhoneNumber from '../components/prebuilt/PhoneNumber'
...
<PhoneInput
   placeholder='Enter phone number'
   value={phone}
   onChange={setPhone}
   inputComponent={CustomPhoneNumber}
/>
...
```

Comment: Nice! This is absolutely what I needed.

Answer (score 5):

There is also a package for Material UI v5 (or MUI) called [Mui tel input](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mui-tel-input) and it's working with React 17 and 18 !

Simply way to use. Phone validation available too.

Check the doc here : https://github.com/viclafouch/mui-tel-input

```js
import React from 'react'
import { MuiTelInput } from 'mui-tel-input'

const MyComponent = () => {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState('')

  const handleChange = (newValue) => {
    setValue(newValue)
  }

  return <MuiTelInput label="Phone" fullWidth value={value} onChange={handleChange} />
}
```

Comment: Hey!, using TS I have an issue with this library, MuiTelInput requires all attributes from a common TextField of MUI lib. What am I making wrong? I mean, I just copied and pasted the same example as you and the documentation says.

Answer (score -1):

This is my component using MUI v5:

Form field

```
//...
const [phone, setPhone]: any = useState();
const handlePhone = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> )=>{
        setPhone(e.target.value)
    }
<TextField onChange={handlePhone} value={phone} variant="outlined"
                                                                   sx={{ '& .MuiOutlinedInput-input': {display: 'flex'}}}
                                                                   InputProps={{
                                                                       inputComponent: PhoneField as any,
                                                                       inputProps: {
                                                                           name: "phone",
                                                                           control: control,
                                                                           international: true,
                                                                           defaultCountry: "US",
                                                                           value: phone,
                                                                       }/>
```

PhoneField

```
interface PhoneNumberProps {
    value?: string;
    placeholder?: string;
    onChange: (event: { target: { value: string } }) => void;
    name: string;
}
export const PhoneField = forwardRef<HTMLElement, PhoneNumberProps>((props, ref:any) => {
    const { onChange, name, placeholder, value, ...other } = props;

    return <PhoneInputWithCountry name={name} ref={ref} placeholder="1 213 123 4567" onChange={(value: string)=>onChange({target:{value}})} {...other}/>
})
```